# Is it possible to remove an operation hook?

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, loopbackjs, strongloop

Let say I have bind an `operation hook` for test purpose like the following:

```
it('verification link confirms mail',function(done){
    var client = app.models.client;
    client.observe('after save', function(ctx, next) {
        if (!ctx.instance.verificationToken){
            next();
            return;
        }
        var link = '/api/clients/confirm?uid=' + ctx.instance.id + '&redirect=/verified&token=' + ctx.instance.verificationToken;
        json('get', link)
            .send()
            .expect(200, function(){
                client.findById(ctx.instance.id, function(err, inst){
                    assert(inst.emailVerified === true);
                    done();
                });
            });
        next();
    });
    client.create({username:'test',email : 'a@b.com', password : 'test'}, function(err){
        if(err) {
            assert.fail('could not create client instance','',err);
        }
    });

});
```

The problem is that all subsequent tests that create a `client` instance have this operation hook. Is there a way to unbind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually browsing `loopback-datasource-juggler` source code I found the way to unbind the `operation hook`. The function `Model.removeObserver('event',call)` does the job. This is the updated code:

```
it('verification link confirms mail',function(done){
    function observeClient(ctx, next) {
        if (!ctx.instance.verificationToken){
            next();
            return;
        }
        var link = '/api/clients/confirm?uid=' + ctx.instance.id + '&redirect=/verified&token=' + ctx.instance.verificationToken;
        json('get', link)
            .send()
            .expect(200, function(){
                client.findById(ctx.instance.id, function(err, inst){
                    assert(inst.emailVerified === true);
                    client.removeObserver('after save',observeClient);//unbind
                    done();
                });
            });
        next();
    }
    var client = app.models.client;
    client.observe('after save', observeClient);
    client.create({username:'andi',email : 'andi@b.com', password : 'test'}, function(err){
        if(err) {
            assert.fail('could not create client instance','',err);
        }
    });
});
```

The test case example can be found [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/master/test/async-observer.test.js#L116)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that loopback provides a way to un-observe safetly an operation hook. I think that they use the`Object.observe` method whis is getting obsolete in some of the javaScript implementations. I suggest to you to try something like:

```
client.unobserve('after save', function (ctx, next) {
        //do something after the change is un-observed in the object
});
```

I hope you to find this useful.

You can read something with more detail [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/unobserve). **It is an obsolete feature so be careful**.